# Every time I run my app in Xcode it asks if I'm sure I want to allow it to run

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sonoma

I'm developing a Mac App in Sonoma.

Every time I run the App from Xcode using the debugger Xcode asks:

[image: Dialogue showing 'AppName is from an unidentified developer and differs from previously opened versions. Are you sure you want to open it?']

> **"AppName" is from an unidentified developer and
> differs from previously opened versions. Are you sure you want
> to open it?**
>
> Opening “TreeView” will allow it to access data from previously used
> versions of “TreeView”.

This is quite annoying – how can I stop this?

Answer (score 14):

The fix I've found for this is to set a development team in my Xcode project, rather than leaving it as "none".

- In Xcode, select your Xcode project to see the project's property viewer.
- On the left bar, select your project's App target in the "Targets" section – mine's called "TreeView".
- Select the "Signing & Capabilities" tab at the top – it's the second one along.
- For "Team" select your personal team.

I found this solution from a link about [macOS Sonoma sandbox security](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/2023/6/1.html).

As the link states, it's not clear if there's some other settings to allow a project without a team (eg, distributed from a git repo, say) to be run without clicking this dialogue all the time. If you've got a more in depth answer than mine or can clarify extra details, I'll happily check yours instead of mine.

Comment: Also make sure that "Signing Certificate" is set to Development, not Sign to Run Locally.